# Javascript splice gives different output

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

Here is a strange behavior I encountered while using splice.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
numbers.splice(0, 0, 4, 5);
console.log(numbers); // This gives output [4, 5, 1, 2, 3] 

console.log([1, 2, 3].splice(0, 0, 4, 5)) // Outputs []
```

Why is that?

Comment: Splice mutates the original array, and returns an array of items removed. Since you don't remove anything, the returned array is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. `splice` returns the array of deleted items, in your case, there are no elements deleted. `splice` actually modifies the original array. Read the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 1):

`Array.splice` function by itself returns the range of elements you have starting from the first argument and ending at the second argument. Everything that comes after the second argument automatically is being added at the end of your original array, BUT it is not returned as a result of the operation.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(numbers.splice(0, 0, 4, 5)) // <- prints nothing because your sequence is from 0 to 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

`splice` method doesn't return the output, rather modifies the original array.

Comment: It does return value, if your range provided has elements inside the original one

Answer (score 0):

#### JavaScript Array splice() replace original array element

```js
array.splice(index, how_many_element, item1, ....., itemX);
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];


console.log(numbers.splice(0, 0, 4, 5)) // <- here index = 0, how_many_element = 0, deferent = 0, that is why prints nothing because your sequence is from 0 to 0.
```

> ***index*** : The position to add/remove items;
> ***how_many_element*** : Number of items to be removed.